# How to configure & use persistent data objects in SAP HANA Cloud?

Tags: java, persistence, hana, sap-business-technology-platform

I want to create a simple project management application in Java at the SAP HANA Cloud Platform. Users can add persons to projects and define the working hours of a person who works on a project.

I created successfully a small application logic. However it's not clear to me how I should define the persistent data objects. And how to store and read the data in the right way.

I created the classes "Project" and "Person" to add data (see below).

How can I create a relationship between them and store the hours of work a person spent on a project?

On an ERM, I know the solution: A 1:n relation between Person and Project and an extra table between them with "projectID","personID" and "workingHours".

So far the app writes data with the function "addNewPerson":

```
addNewPerson : function( sFirstName, sLastName, oTable ) {  
          var _this = this;  
          _this.odataServiceUrl = personsListOdataServiceUrl;  
          jQuery.ajax({  
             url : _this.odataServiceUrl + "/Person?$format=json",  
             type : 'POST',  
             contentType : 'application/json',  
             data : JSON.stringify({  
                                     firstName : sFirstName,  
                                     lastName : sLastName  
                                  }),  
             success : function(data) {  
               _this.getView().getModel().refresh();  
               oTable.unbindRows().bindRows("/Person");  
      },  
             error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {  
           sap.ui.commons.MessageBox.alert("Failed to add person: " + textStatus+ "\n" + errorThrown);  
             }  
      }); },
```

To read the data, I simply bind the rows to the object.

So, how can I create the data objects the right way? And how can I read and write the data to the objects?

**Person.java:**

```
package com.sap.netweaver.cloud.sample;
import javax.persistence.*;
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_PERSON")
@NamedQuery(name = "AllPersons", query = "select p from Person p")

public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    @Basic
    private String firstName;
    @Basic
    private String lastName;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String param) {
        this.firstName = param;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String param) {
        this.lastName = param;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
}
```

**Project.java:**

```
package com.sap.netweaver.cloud.sample;

import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "T_PROJECT")
@NamedQuery(name = "AllProjects", query = "select p from Project p")
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    @Basic
    private String projectName;
    @Basic
    private String projectDesc;
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setProjectName(String param) {
        this.projectName = param;
    }

    public String getProjectName() {
        return projectName;
    }

    public void setProjectDesc(String param) {
        this.projectDesc = param;
    }

    public String getProjectDesc() {
        return projectDesc;
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to check out the blog post from Timo Lakner at http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/cloud-platform/blog/2014/03/04/sflight-sample-showing-how-to-use-jco-and-rfc-to-integrate-with-on-premise-abap-system He uses similar technologies (JCo), but maybe you can re-use some patterns from the UI he provides. Best, Rui

Answer (score 0):

First to your question regarding the connection between the person and the project. Since one project can have multiple persons I guess, you need a

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "projectEntity", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<Persons> persons= new ArrayList<Persons>();
```

on the project side and on the person side

```
@JoinColumn(name = "projectEntity")// JPA creates join column for you with the project id - see wiki oneToMany JPA example
private Project project;
```

For testing I strongly recomment the following steps:

1. Start from the JPA example in the SAP HCP sdk: neo-java-web-sdk-2.36.4\samples\persistence-with-jpa
2. Once you understood the example (create,persit,find), you add the 1:N
   relation by adding a second entity with the coding described above.
   3).
3. If this is working I would recommend going from the default memory database set in your local Tomcat or Java EE server to a real local DB. Apache Derby worked fine for me there. You find various youtube videos where the installation of derby is explained.